# Android: Accessing list of local resources in Android

Tags: android, resources, local, drawable

How can I access the list of drawables under my project "res/drawables"? Im new to Android I've seen an example like this:

```
Field[] drawables = android.R.drawable.class.getFields();
for (Field f : drawables) {
    try {
        System.out.println("R.drawable." + f.getName());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But this lists all the default drawables, not what I want:( I want to access those files and have their names to generate an xml, because my layout will be dynamic (number of drawables may differ from time to time).

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

> android.R.drawable.class.getFields();

with

```
your.application.package.R.drawable.class.getFields();
```

to access your drawables.

Comment: thanks for the reply:) i found a way around this problem. i can read the resource names. then im trying to generate main.xml file inside onCreate() before setContentView to R.main. Its not working but im trying this because I have a viewflipper with multiple images in it and I can only do it using main.xml. Is it possible to have multiple images inside one ViewFlipper through java code?<
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are probably wanting Context.getResources...

[Accessing Resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)

Comment: thanks for the reply:) i found a way around this problem. i can read the resource names. then im trying to generate main.xml file inside onCreate() before setContentView to R.main. Its not working but im trying this because I have a viewflipper with multiple images in it and I can only do it using main.xml. Is it possible to have multiple images inside one ViewFlipper through java code? Thanks

Comment: @dramaticlook No problem :) Check this thread out as it may provide an answer to your issue... [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934176/android-viewflipper-multiple-images](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934176/android-viewflipper-multiple-images)

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to follow a naming convention for all your drawables. Say prefix them with your app name 'app'.

```
for(Field f:drawables){
    if(f.getName().startsWith("app")){
       //Your drawable.
    }
}
```